# How do you say “watch out for them” and “watch out for it”?

Tags: pronoms

[image]

I would like to know if I’m using indirect pronouns correctly in these examples. Btw, I’m a beginner, so if you decide to give any explanations, please make them as simple as possible. Thank you! :)

1. “Watch out for those boys.” is « Prenez garde à ces garçons ». Therefore, “Watch out for them.” is « Prenez-**leur** garde ». Is this correct?
2. “Watch out for cars.” is « Prenez gardes aux voitures ». Therefore, “Watch out for them." is « Prenez-**y** garde ». Is this correct?
3. “Watch out for black ice.” is « Prenez garde au verglas ». Therefore, “Watch out for it” is « Prenez-**y** garde ». Is this correct?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/prendre-garde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In modern French you are more likely to say "Fais attention à ces garçons.". "Prends garde à ces garçons." is also used but it is probably more used in the written language.
   "Prenez-leur garde" is not corect.
2. "Prenez-y garde" is correct.
3. "Prenez-y garde" is correct.

([TLFi, Y²](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y)) I. − [Y, pronom […] représente un nom, un pronom. ou une proposition entière]

*Addition* Here is more information that you should try to understand: [réf.](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-personnels).

> Certains verbes et certaines locutions verbales que l’on construit avec la préposition à sont suivis du pronom tonique complément, mais seulement si la préposition introduit une personne (quelqu’un) et non une chose.

**Verbe**                                                                   **Exemple**

avoir affaire à qqn                Vous avez affaire à un expert. Vous avez affaire à moi.

avoir recours à qqn                 Pierre est avocat. Tu devrais avoir recours à lui.

faire attention à qqn              Les enfants d’Anne sont entre de bonnes mains, la baby-sitter fait toujours très attention à eux.

penser à qqn                        Je pense à toi tous les jours.

s’habituer à qqn                   Après trois ans de colocation, je m’entends bien avec Yannick. Je me suis habituée à lui.

s’intéresser à qqn             Tu t’intéresses à elle ? Si tu veux, je peux te la présenter.

songer à qqn                      Mes amis m’ont manqué lorsque j’étais à l’étranger. J’ai souvent songé à eux.

tenir à qqn                          Je ne veux pas qu’il parte. Je tiens beaucoup à lui.

s’adresser à qqn                 Je vais aller voir M. Dupont. Je m’adresse toujours à lui si j'ai des questions.

se fier à qqn                    Je ne fais confiance à personne. Je ne me fie qu’à moi.

Here is an audio complement you might like: [pronunciation ot tonic pronouns](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/pronoms_toniques.htm)

Comment: Hey @LPH .  Thanks for the help. :) Why is number (1) grammatically incorrect? I thought “verb + à + **noun**” changes to “verb - **indirect object pronoun**” when the **noun** is a person. In my case, the noun is a group of boys, which means we use the indirect object pronoun **leur**, right? Or is it the case that (1) is grammatically correct, it’s just that (1) isn’t used in modern french which is why you said it was wrong?

Comment: @CubbyKushi No, it's not; the pronoun in this case is "**eux**", and then you have to use the prepositoion "à"; finally the place of this indirect object is after "garde".  So, you should write "Prends garde à eux.".

Comment: @CubbyKushi Don't take me wrong, **it is** used in modern French; however you will more often hear "fais attention…", which means exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @LPH !!! 

Comment: @CubbyKushi You welcome!

Comment: I just saw the constructions where the *pronom tonique* (which I’m guessing are the same thing as stressed pronouns) follows à instead. Thank you so much @LPH, this is so very very very helpful!!!!! 